# need to set headers on guzzle request

Tags: guzzle, drupal-8

I need to add the type of headers to the guzzle request below, but cannot figure out how to put it in without getting an error
This is what I want to add :

```
$command->set('command.headers', array('content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

to this code below:

```
<?php
  $url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();

  $post_data = array('color' => 'red');
  $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'form_params' => $post_data,
    'verify' => false
    ]);
  $body = $response->getBody();
  dsm($body);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I needed use the Guzzle at D8 to make a POST I passed the Content-Type like this:

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();

  $post_data = array('color' => 'red');
  $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'body' => rawData($post_data),
  ]);
  $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
  $status = $response->getStatusCode();
```

A good idea is use the D8 Dependency Injection to pass the HTTP_CLIENT.

Comment: thanks, but where would you add the 'verify'=>false  which I also need to send?

Comment: InvalidArgumentException: Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request. in GuzzleHttp\Client->invalidBody() (line 402 of C:\drupaldevsites\drupal-wcms-migration\docroot\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php).

Comment: The following worked for me . thanks $url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
 $post_data = $form_state->cleanValues()->getValues();
 $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'form_params' => $post_data,
    'verify'=>false,
  ]);
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $status = $response->getStatusCode();
    dsm($body);
    dsm($status);

Comment: Nice! Yes how you are using application/x-www-form-urlencoded you need use the 'form_params' Key.